# Creating large XML Trees in R

Tags: xml, r, performance

I'm trying to create a large XML tree in R. Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
library(XML)
N = 100000#In practice is larger  10^8/ 10^9
seq = newXMLNode("sequence")
pars = as.character(1:N)
for(i in 1:N)
    newXMLNode("Parameter", parent=seq, attrs=c(id=pars[i]))
```

When N is about N^6 this takes about a minute, N^7 takes about forty minutes. Is there anyway to speed this up?

Using the paste command:

```
par_tmp = paste('<Parameter id="', pars, '"/>', sep="")
```

takes less than a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend profiling the function using `Rprof` or the [`profr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/profr/) package.  This will show you where your bottleneck is, and you then you can think about ways to either optimize the function or change the way that you're using it.

Your `paste` example would be much faster in part because it's vectorized.  For a more fair comparison, you can see the difference there by looping over `paste` as you are currently doing with `newXMLNode` and see the difference in timing.

*Edit:*

Here is the output from profiling your loop with `profr`.

```
library(profr)
xml.prof <- profr(for(i in 1:N) 
    newXMLNode("Parameter", parent=seq, attrs=c(id=pars[i])))
plot(xml.prof)
```

There is nothing especially obvious in here about places that you can improve this.  I see that it spends a reasonable amount of time in the `%in%` function, so improving that would reduce the overall time somewhat (although you still need to iterate over this repeatedly, so it won't make a huge difference).  The best solution would be to rewrite `newXMLNode` as a vectorized function so you can skip the `for` loop entirely.
[image]